# What attribute shows that a native app element is disabled?

Tags: selenium, reactjs, react-native, automation, appium

I have a button that, when disabled, has a `disabled` attribute on web. However, when I view that same button on iOS or Android native, not only does it not have a `disabled` attribute, but it has an `enabled` attribute marked as true. Why don't native elements have the `disabled` attribute, or why do they always have an `enabled` one that is true?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
driver.findElement("your locator").isEnabled();
```

This will return true if element is enabled otherwise false.

Comment: Unfortunately, this always returned true for native elements; I'm not sure if it's because "enabled" is always true, or if there's never a "disabled" attribute, but, either way, it seems to always think of everything as enabled.